# Navision + sharepoint.

Tags: sharepoint-designer, bcs

For the last couple of weeks we have been struggling with an issue that we could not solve. This issue are concerning Sharepoint and Navision 2009. So we really hope that you would find a solution. But here it goes.  I have chosen to divide the question into different parts. First I will explain our problem. Second I will come will come up with an explanation on how is our setup.

**Setup:**

As I mentioned a little earlier this question is about Sharepoint and Navision. We have installed Navision on a three tier setup. We have also made Web services inside Navision so we could contact Navision from outside code and get relevant data out of Navision. We are using SQL server as server tier. Those Navision webservices is being consumed by a WCF service, that is being hosted in IIS. We are getting a list of customers out from Navision.  All this works perfectly and without any Errors.  And we are able to get relevant data out from the webservice.

The other part is Sharepoint 2010. We have made a developersite where all the relevant data should be posted. We have chosen to use Sharepoint designer to make External content types so we could consume the webservice that have been hosted in IIS. We have also been doing a secure store setup in sharepoint.

**Our problem:**

Every time we try to make a list from the data that is hosted in IIS, it fails with different exceptions.

Our first problem is this in ULSviewer:

> Error while executing web part:
>   Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.MissingMetadataPropertyException:
>   The Property with Name 'SecondarySsoApplicationId' is missing on the
>   LobSystemInstance (External System Instance).

In BCS Tester Man, We are getting the following error:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.

(we have turned on that reporting service).

In sharepoint we are getting the following error.

> Business Data Connectivity is configured incorrectly. Administrators,
>   see the server log for more information. Correlation
>   ID:8f27bc5b-4507-48e9-81ac-b7f91311a8d3

I have read dozens of articles on what I should do, and it does not help just to filter what you are getting in return.

I really hope that I provided you with some relevant information towards solving this. But if there is anything that I could help you to understand this issue any further, feel free to ask me questions.

Below there is the code that is consuming the webservice we are using:

```
public Customerlist[] getCustomer(string account_codefield)
    {
        Customerlist_Filter filter = new Customerlist_Filter();
        filter.Field = Customerlist_Fields.Name;
        filter.Criteria = "*Jan* | *Jens*";
        Customerlist[] Customer = new Customerlist[30];
        List<string> Credentials = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            Customerlist_Filter[] PersonFilter = new Customerlist_Filter[] { filter };

            Customer = ConnectorClassCustomerNAV(PersonFilter);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return Customer;

    }

public NavClient.Customerlist[] ConnectorClassCustomerNAV(NavClient.Customerlist_Filter[] Filters)
    {
        Customerlist_Service CL = new Customerlist_Service();
        CL.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        Customerlist[] Customer = new Customerlist[30];

        try
        {
            Customer = CL.ReadMultiple(Filters, null, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        return Customer;                
    }
```